# How do I remove these elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to Angular and Im helping a friend....they have some checkboxes built with '+' and '-'signs to expand collapse.  All checkboxes by default  have the "+"....I have a JS function that loops through and finds if the node has children or not.  If the length is '0' I want to remove the '+' and the '-' all

```
<div ng-repeat="category in list>
    <a href="" ng-show="!dList" ng-click="depList=!depList">+</a>
    <a href="" ng-show="dList" ng-click="depList=!depList">-</a> 
    <a href="" ng-click="dList=!depList"></a>      
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="category['@attributes'].isChecked" ng-click="toggleCheckBox1(this,1)">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var eObject= $scope.List;
for(var m = 0; m < eObject.length; m++){
    if(eObject[m].node.length == 0){
        //REMOVE + OR - SIGN HERE!! 
    } else{
        eObject[m].node.length );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just add the following to the ng-show directive to look at the length of the category.node.length > 0:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in list>
<a href="" ng-show="!dList && category.node.length > 0" ng-click="depList=!depList">+</a>
<a href="" ng-show="dList && category.node.length > 0" ng-click="depList=!depList">-</a> 
<a href="" ng-click="dList=!depList"></a>      
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="category['@attributes'].isChecked" ng-click="toggleCheckBox1(this,1)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what chubbsondubs said, however, you could simplify the html like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in list">
    <div ng-show="category.node.length">
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" etc>
</div>
```